# Why one test is going well and over not?

Tags: python, testing

**I have two almost same tests.**

Why one test is going ok 1 one.  But 2nd   give error AssertionError: <Post: Тест 9> not found in <Page 1 of 2>

We same object {Post} I put to assert.

```
imports......

class PostPagesTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.user = User.objects.create_user(username='NameTest')
        cls.group = Group.objects.create(
            title='Тестовая группа',
            slug='test-slug',
            description='Тестовое описание',
        )
        
        cls.post = Post.objects.create(
            author=cls.user,
            text='Тестовый пост для теста',
            group=cls.group
        )



def test_1post_added_to_page(self):
        """ One post - index
            OK   
        """

        response = self.authorized_client.get(reverse('posts:index'))

        res = response.context['page_obj']

        post_ = self.post

        self.assertIn(self.post, res)
        

def test_2post_added_to_page(self):
    """ 13 posts - index
        NOT OK
    """

    posts = Post.objects.bulk_create(
        [
            Post(
                text=f'Тест {n}',
                author=self.user,
                group=self.group
            )
            for n in range(13)
        ]
    )
    
    post_ = posts[9]

    response = self.authorized_client.get(reverse('posts:index'))

    res = response.context['page_obj'][0]

    self.assertIn(post_, res)
```

I expected that both tests are going well